# Vuex object duplicate instead of updated

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

Instead of updating the current object in vuex-bindings, a new one gets created.
The database is a cloud-firestore from google.

I'm using Vue, vuex, vuetify, google-cloud-firestore and google-storage in my app.

This is my store-module for this particular part:

```js
import { catsColl, productsColl } from '../firebase'

const state = {
  catOrProducts: [],
}

const mutations = {
  setCatProd(state, val) {
    state.catOrProducts = val
  },
}

const actions = {
  // https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuexfire.html#firestoreaction

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  async bindCatsWithProducts({ commit, dispatch }, CatID) {
    const contain = CatID || 'nC'
    const arr = []

    catsColl.where('parentCat', '==', contain).orderBy('name', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(cat => {
          arr.push({ id: cat.id, ...cat.data() })
        })
      })

    productsColl.where('isSold', '==', true).where('cats', 'array-contains', contain).orderBy('name', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(prod => {
          arr.push({ id: prod.id, ...prod.data() })
        })
      })

    commit('setCatProd', arr)
  },
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
}
```

The view is handled in my component inside a container. The two components are for products and categories, since i want to show them differently.

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row
    align="center"
    justify="center"
  >
    <v-col
      v-for="catOrProduct in catOrProducts"
      :key="catOrProduct.id"
      @click.prevent="leftClickProd($event, catOrProduct)"
      @contextmenu.prevent="rightClickProd($event, catOrProduct)"
    >
      <TileCat
        v-if="typeof(catOrProduct.parentCat) == 'string'"
        :src="catOrProduct.pictureURL"
        :name="catOrProduct.name"
      />
      <TileProduct
        v-if="catOrProduct.isSold"
        :name="catOrProduct.name"
        :src="catOrProduct.pictureURL"
        :store-inv="catOrProduct.storeInv"
        :warning-store-inv="catOrProduct.warningStoreInv"
        :min-store-inv="catOrProduct.minStoreInv"
        :bar-inv="catOrProduct.barInv"
        :warning-bar-inv="catOrProduct.warningBarInv"
        :min-bar-inv="catOrProduct.minBarInv"
        :is-used-directly="catOrProduct.isUsedDirectly"
        :is-active="catOrProduct.isActive"
        :sell-price="catOrProduct.sellPrice"
      />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

**EDIT 26.09.20**

The two components used in there (tiles) look like this (though the product one is more complex, with some dynamic class allocation)

```
<template>
  <v-hover
    v-slot:default="{ hover }"
    class="unselectable"
  >
    <v-card :elevation="hover ? 6 : 2">
      <v-img
        class="white--text align-end"
        :src="src"
        gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
        aspect-ratio="1"
        height="17rem"
        contain
      >
        <v-card-title class="white--text ">
          {{ name }}
        </v-card-title>
      </v-img>
    </v-card>
  </v-hover>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    src: {
      type: String,
      default: '@/assets/placeholder.png'
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT END**

Everything looks fine:
[image: view before update]

When I update my product (new price) it gets reloaded automatically **but** there is no update happening.
Instead it spawns a second object.
[image: view after update]

Additionally the error `[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'TtUJJ0Agvd3DRBynmYgk'. This may cause an update error.` appears.

I have the `"v-for" key` set properly to the ID of my product/category. There are no duplicates.
I tried to run with

```
v-for="(catOrProduct, index) in catOrProducts"
:key="index"
```

But this only removes the `duplicated keys detected` error.
There are still objects created.

I also removed the categories out of the equation but even without them, I still get duplicates.

If i make more changes it creates a new object every time!
***Reloading the entire page reverts back to showing only the correct product*** to the error is not in the database.

How do i make this kind of binding go the rigth way?

Comment: To gather some information, do the components share the same data object?

Comment: @MrTech i've edited my question and added the tile code. They just take some props. They don't even know their ID. Do i need to give them one?

Comment: I've found this link and think it may be related to what is happening https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7805

Comment: Basically, it looks like a bug with Vue.

Comment: "Components are duplicated when they share the same data object #7805"